# Init django app with docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm newbie in docker-compose and I have a docker with my django instance and a mysql database. I would like to create a self autoconfigured container which run a command only on the first docker run. In this command I would like to do the following tasks:

1. make initial database migrations
2. create the admin superuser
3. import a mysql backup into the database

After this the system should continue launching the django test webserver.

Are there any way to tell docker-compose to run a command just on it first run or are there any alternative in django to control if the system is already configured and updated?

In order to clarify here are my dockfile and docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM python:3.4
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/

####################

version: '2'
services:
db:
   image: "mysql:5.6"
   ports:
     - 3306:3306
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
     MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxx
     MYSQL_USER: xxxxx
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxx
 web:
   build: .
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   volumes:
     - .:/code
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   depends_on:
     - db
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could roll your own Dockerfile to run those commands

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't really know if a simple modification of the dockerfile will works because I'm using the database as an independant image from my django.

Comment: I understand that. I was saying you make a database container (separately from django) with a layer that runs  your scripts and imports. After you have an image, Docker isn't really designed to "run something only once" (i.e be stateful). At least, that's my experience with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the comments of @cricket_007, finally I have found a tricky solution to solve the problem. I have created a sh script for the database service and for my web service. Additionally I have created two version files in my folder, web_local.version and web_server.version.

The web_local.version has been added to my .gitignore because this file is used to storage the current app version.

The start_web.sh script is a simple script that compare if the folder contains a web_local.version file. In that case the project has been configured in the past and the script checks if the current app version is updated compared with the server version. In the case all is up to date simply run a webserver otherwise run a migrate to update the models and then run the webserver.

Here is the web_start.sh script for references:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE="web_local.version"

if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
   echo "File $FILE exist."
   if diff ./web_server.version ./web_local.version > /dev/null;
   then
      echo "model version up to date :)"
   else
      echo "model updated!!"
      python manage.py migrate
      cp ./web_server.version ./$FILE
  fi
else
  echo "File $FILE does not exist"
  sleep 10 #added because the first time db take a long time to init and the script doesn't wait until db is finished
  cp ./web_server.version ./$FILE
  python manage.py migrate
fi
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I suppose that there are more formal solutions but this solutions is functional for my case because it allows our team to maintain the same mock database and same models synced through git and we have a zero time configuration environment running just with one command.